# Alarm and Alarm Template table in clock app

Tags: android, database, sqlite, design-patterns

I am little confused about this approach , and don't understand purpose of this. 
I am discovering default desk clock app from android 4.4 an have noticed something weird. In `ClockDatabaseHelper` class there are several tables are created in database.

```
   // Database and table names
    static final String DATABASE_NAME = "alarms.db";
    static final String OLD_ALARMS_TABLE_NAME = "alarms";
    static final String ALARMS_TABLE_NAME = "alarm_templates";
    static final String INSTANCES_TABLE_NAME = "alarm_instances";
    static final String CITIES_TABLE_NAME = "selected_cities";
```

So first string is clear. The second string why does it named as OLD_ALARMS and real name of the table is alarms. Why does it has such name ? And what is the real puprose of this. 
Next , third string has value "alarm_templates" ... WHY ? What word "templates" represents ? Why does it have such name ?
Instance table is for current state of alarm ...But it still not clear for me why can't we write directly to alarm table. 
Please explain what is the goal of doing all this stuff ?

```
 @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int currentVersion) {
        LogUtils.v("Upgrading alarms database from version "
                + oldVersion + " to " + currentVersion);

        if (oldVersion <= VERSION_6) {
            // These were not used in DB_VERSION_6, so we can just drop them.
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + INSTANCES_TABLE_NAME + ";");
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + CITIES_TABLE_NAME + ";");

            // Create new alarms table and copy over the data
            createAlarmsTable(db);
            createInstanceTable(db);
            createCitiesTable(db);

            LogUtils.i("Copying old alarms to new table");
            String[] OLD_TABLE_COLUMNS = {
                    "_id",
                    "hour",
                    "minutes",
                    "daysofweek",
                    "enabled",
                    "vibrate",
                    "message",
                    "alert",
            };
            Cursor cursor = db.query(OLD_ALARMS_TABLE_NAME, OLD_TABLE_COLUMNS,
                    null, null, null, null, null);
            Calendar currentTime = Calendar.getInstance();
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                Alarm alarm = new Alarm();
                alarm.id = cursor.getLong(0);
                alarm.hour = cursor.getInt(1);
                alarm.minutes = cursor.getInt(2);
                alarm.daysOfWeek = new DaysOfWeek(cursor.getInt(3));
                alarm.enabled = cursor.getInt(4) == 1;
                alarm.vibrate = cursor.getInt(5) == 1;
                alarm.label = cursor.getString(6);

                String alertString = cursor.getString(7);
                if ("silent".equals(alertString)) {
                    alarm.alert = Alarm.NO_RINGTONE_URI;
                } else {
                    alarm.alert = TextUtils.isEmpty(alertString) ? null : Uri.parse(alertString);
                }

                // Save new version of alarm and create alarminstance for it
                db.insert(ALARMS_TABLE_NAME, null, Alarm.createContentValues(alarm));
                if (alarm.enabled) {
                    AlarmInstance newInstance = alarm.createInstanceAfter(currentTime);
                    db.insert(INSTANCES_TABLE_NAME, null,
                            AlarmInstance.createContentValues(newInstance));
                }
            }
            cursor.close();

            LogUtils.i("Dropping old alarm table");
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + OLD_ALARMS_TABLE_NAME + ";");
        }
    }
```

And here is method where OLD_ALARMS_TABLE_NAME is used - onUpgrade we just copy old table to new , but we never wrote to her. Please explain what happens here. Thanks

**EDIT**

Thanks to **CL.** and during writing post I got it.

This is for updating old database table here is code from old app

```
private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "alarms.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 5;

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE alarms (" +
                   "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
                   "hour INTEGER, " +
                   "minutes INTEGER, " +
                   "daysofweek INTEGER, " +
                   "alarmtime INTEGER, " +
                   "enabled INTEGER, " +
                   "vibrate INTEGER, " +
                   "message TEXT, " +
                   "alert TEXT);");

        // insert default alarms
        String insertMe = "INSERT INTO alarms " +
                "(hour, minutes, daysofweek, alarmtime, enabled, vibrate, message, alert) " +
                "VALUES ";
        db.execSQL(insertMe + "(7, 0, 127, 0, 0, 1, '', '');");
        db.execSQL(insertMe + "(8, 30, 31, 0, 0, 1, '', '');");
        db.execSQL(insertMe + "(9, 00, 0, 0, 0, 1, '', '');");
    }
```

So here is name is hardcoded in insert statement. I think this is bad approac , firstly all variable of constant values are not constant variables. And here is sql openhelper is nested static class. I don't know , maybe I am wrong .

Comment: Have a look at earlier versions of this app.

Comment: Thanks bro , I have get during writing post. And you have confirmed that. Here is part of code from previous Alarm clock app. Post your comment as an answer I will confirm it.

Comment: You can answer yourself.

Comment: You have helped me , so post you answer. And if you have time please say something about approach in earlier apps.